# How to determine the least distance covered by a light crossing a crystal?

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure shown in the lower part shows a sucrose crystal that is
> about to be studied for its optical properties. The crystal is a
> pyramid whose base is an equilateral triangle $\triangle\,BCD$ and its
> faces are right isosceles triangles with a common vertex at $A$.
> Knowing this, a bright red flashing light is passed from vertex $B$
> towards a point $P$ on edge $CD$ and from there it goes to a point $Q$
> of the edge $AC$ to return to point $B$. If the length of the route is
> needed to be minimum. Determine the angle $\angle\,PQA$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&135^{\circ}\\
2.&105^{\circ}\\
3.&120^{\circ}\\
4.&150^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

I'm very confused exactly on how to achieve the required condition of the minimum path possible for the light to cross the directions indicated in the crystal.

In other words, how to ensure that the path taken by the light is the least possible?. Can this problem be solved relying only using **Euclidean postulates**?

So far the only thing which I can spot is that:

$\angle ABD= \angle ADB =\angle ADC = \angle ACD =45^{\circ}$

$\angle CBD = \angle BDC = \angle BCD =60^{\circ}$

To me the biggest source of confusion is **how** to get that angle which is being asked, $\angle PQA?$, I think that since it will be required that is to be maximum then it will be wide enough to reduce the distance covered by the light pulses.

But I don't know what else can be found from these relations. **Please include a drawing or diagram in the answer**. As because this figure is in 3-D it is isn't easy to spot how to find the least distance. Can someone help me with this?.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the net of the sucrose crystal.

[image]

( When the net is folded into the sucrose crystal, $A = A' = A''$, $B = B'$ and $Q = Q'$. )

The minimum length of the route = $BB'$

$\angle PQA = \angle PQ'A' = \frac{180° - (60° + 45° + 45°)}{2} + 60° + 45° = 120°$

Comment: excellent approach !